# Convert date into number

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have a table as under

```
AAA 28/01/2016
```

I tried many option like changing format. Datevalue, Datevalue(text...) functions but the date is not being converted into number.

Comment: which excel version?
are you using vb-macros? apache POI or what lib for trying to achieve this? weneed information

Comment: its excel 2013 and its on a xlsm file.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got `AAA 28/01/2016` in either one cell or two and want to make that text into an actual date or even a number.

[image: text_to_date]

The formulas in C1:C2 are,

```
=DATE(RIGHT(B1, 4), MID(B1, 8, 2), MID(B1, 5, 2))    ◄ C1
=DATE(RIGHT(B2, 4), MID(B2, 4, 2), MID(B2, 1, 2))    ◄ C2
```

Format however you want after you have made the text-to-date conversion. To avoid ambiguity, the above uses `dd-mmm-yyyy_)` . A true number would be `0` to show 42,397. Note that text (by default) is left-aligned in the cell while dates and numbers are right-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Use below function.

```
=TEXT(A1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Not working sir, output is same as input. Iformatted to number but still output same. Thanks Sir for reply

Comment: You want to separate date? I could not understand you. I thought you want to datevalue equal number.

Comment: yes sir i wanted date value equal number.However output same as input.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

```
=--A1
```

Then format the cell as you want.  The `--` will change it to a number.